# Batch IF Statement Block Syntax

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, syntax

I have the following code (in batch) to test part of a larger code that isnt working:

```
@echo off
set /a slotted55=8
set /a place=55
set /a key3=8
set /a key1=0
set /a key2=0
set /a key4=0
set /a key5=0
set /a key6=0
set /a strike=0
 if %place%==55 (
    if %key1%==%slotted55% (
        set key1=V
        set slotted55=V
        goto 5x5one
    ) else (
        if %key2%==%slotted55% (
            set key2=V
            set slotted55=V
            goto 5x5one
        )
    ) else (
        if %key3%==%slotted55% (
            set key3=V
            set slotted55=V
            goto 5x5one
        )
    ) else (
        if %key4%==%slotted55% (
            set key4=V
            set slotted55=V
            goto 5x5one
        )
    ) else (
        if %key5%==%slotted55% (
            set key5=V
            set slotted55=V
            goto 5x5one
        )
    ) else (
        if %key6%==%slotted55% (
            set key6=V
            set slotted55=V
            goto 5x5one
        )
    ) else (
        set /a strike=%strike% +1
        if %strike%==3 goto gameover
        set %slotted55%=X
        goto 5x5one
    )
 )
:gameover
echo gameover
pause
exit
:5x5one
echo good
pause
```

For some reason, it keeps crashing. I've looked at multiple other questions, but none of them seem to fit this situation. All the variables seem correct, and there are no missing operands, but its not like batch gives you an error message. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You do not need any of those `else` statements at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, you do not require any of the `else` statements, also as your opening `if` statement does not have an `else`, you should begin by using the opposite comparison, thus not having everything nested into one set of parentheses.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "place=55"
Set /A "key3=slotted55=8"
Set /A "key1=key2=key4=key5=key6=strike=0"

If "%place%" NEq "55" GoTo gameover

If "%key1%" == "%slotted55%" (
    Set "key1=V"
    Set "slotted55=V"
    GoTo 5x5one
)
If "%key2%" == "%slotted55%" (
    Set "key2=V"
    Set "slotted55=V"
    GoTo 5x5one
)
If "%key3%" == "%slotted55%" (
    Set "key3=V"
    Set "slotted55=V"
    GoTo 5x5one
)
If "%key4%" == "%slotted55%" (
    Set "key4=V"
    Set "slotted55=V"
    GoTo 5x5one
)
If "%key5%" == "%slotted55%" (
    Set "key5=V"
    Set "slotted55=V"
    GoTo 5x5one
)
If "%key6%" == "%slotted55%" (
    Set "key6=V"
    Set "slotted55=V"
    GoTo 5x5one
)
Set /A strike += 1
If %strike% Equ 3 GoTo gameover
Set "slotted55=X"
GoTo 5x5one

:gameover
Echo gameover
Pause
Exit /B

:5x5one
Echo good
Pause
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Because of where you put your `)`s, all of your `else` statements are looking at each other instead of the other `if` statements that you've written. Right now, your logic looks something like this:

```
if "%x%"=="5" (
    echo X is 5
) else (
    echo X is not 5
) else (
    echo X is somehow neither 5 nor is it not 5
)
```

If you combine your `else` with the next `if`, your logic makes sense again.

```
set /a strike=0
if %place%==55 (
    if %key1%==%slotted55% (
        set key1=V
        set slotted55=V
        goto 5x5one
    ) else if %key2%==%slotted55% (
        set key2=V
        set slotted55=V
        goto 5x5one
    ) else if %key3%==%slotted55% (
        set key3=V
        set slotted55=V
        goto 5x5one
    ) else if %key4%==%slotted55% (
        set key4=V
        set slotted55=V
        goto 5x5one
    ) else if %key5%==%slotted55% (
        set key5=V
        set slotted55=V
        goto 5x5one
    ) else if %key6%==%slotted55% (
        set key6=V
        set slotted55=V
        goto 5x5one
    ) else (
        set /a strike=%strike% +1
        if %strike%==3 goto gameover
        set %slotted55%=X
        goto 5x5one
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working with incrementing numbers here, you can just use a for loop and have a single if statement inside a `for` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a slotted55=8, place=55, key3=8, key1=0, key2=0, key4=0, key5=0, key6=0, strike=0
if %place% neq %slotted55% goto :gameover
for /L %%i in (1,1,6) do (
       if !key%%i! equ %slotted55% (
            set "key%%i=V"
            set "slotted55=V"
            goto :5x5one
    ) 
)
:gameover
set /a strike+=1
if %strike% equ 3 (
    echo gameover
    pause
    exit
)
set "slotted55=X"

:5x5one
echo good
pause
```

For now, there seems to be something missing here though, you will never reach `strike=3` unless you have a `goto` to return to the loop. So this code will work as yours would have without all the `else` statements.